If statement on an unset variable
I have an issue with an if statement.
If (($null -eq $success) -or ($success -eq $false)) {
  Write-Host "Hi!"
}

If $success is not defined (doesn't exist) the above will trigger still ..
PS C:\> $success
PS C:\> $success -eq $false
False
PS C:\> $success -eq $true
False
PS C:\> $success = $false
PS C:\> $success -eq $false
True
PS C:\> $success -eq $true
False
PS C:\>

..since an undefined variable is neither $true or $false hence its $false.
I would like that an unset variable doesn't "enter" the If statement and when the variable is $false it does. How can i achieve this?

You can use the Get-Variable cmdlet to see if the variable is defined. From there, you can use an "and" in the if statement to check if both: the variable exists AND if it is set to true.

"I would like that an unset variable doesn't "enter" the If statement and when the variable is $false it does." then remove the first conditional clause? $null -eq $success is not needed in that case.

Enforce Better Script Practices by Using Set-StrictMode


To categorically rule out entering the body of your if statement if a given variable doesn't exist, use a Test-Path call with a path based on the Variable: drive exposed by the variable provider:
if ((Test-Path Variable:success) -and $success -eq $false) { # ...

As an aside:

It's usually better to use -not $variable (or ! $variable) rather than $variable -eq $false

This is not only more concise, but also forces conversion of the value of $variable to a Boolean, so that any value can be negated, based on the rules described in the about_Booleans help topic.

E.g., -not '', -not $null, and -not @() all indicate $true, because these values are coerced to $false

Therefore, given that non-existent variables evaluate to $null by default, you could use -not $success alone if you wanted to treat the non-existence of variable $success the same as as its value being $false (or some other value that is coerced to $false).




To correct your statement, an undefined variable is $null not $false.

..since an undefined variable is neither $true or $false hence its $false.

If you want to enter the condition when $success is $false you can simply remove the first conditional clause:
If ($success -eq $false) {
  Write-Host "Hi!"
}

If you want to avoid any type of coercion done by PowerShell, i.e. 0 -eq $false being true, you can use [bool]::Equals or $false.Equals(...):
If ([bool]::Equals($success, $false)) {
  Write-Host "Hi!"
}

